# bcc32 コマンドが認識されないのは何故？

Tags: c, コマンドプロンプト

C言語です。画像のオレンジ色で囲まれている所なのですが、コマンドプロンプトでbcc32が認識されていない(？)のは何故でしょうか。また、どうすれば改善されるでしょうか。

工業高校の情報技術科1年なんですが、プログラム実習ではbcc32を使うと教わり、問題なくいけました。ですが自宅のパソコンでやってみると通りません。何か設定をいじるんでしょうか。

```
C:\study>bcc32 hello.c
'bcc32' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

[image]

Comment: cドライブの真下にstudy→hello.c　となっております。

Comment: 学校で使っているパソコンの設定がどうなっているのかを先生に教えてもらって来ましょう。そして、自宅のパソコンの設定を学校のパソコンの設定と同じにしましょう。そうすれば、自宅のパソコンでの操作と、学校のパソコンでの操作が同じになります。

Answer (score 2):

まっさきに考えられるのは bcc32 がインストールされていないことです。インストールした覚えが無ければ、インストールしてください。

次に考えられるのは [PATH](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/37237/19110) の設定をしていないことです。本来はインストール手順のどこかで PATH の設定をしているのではないかと思います。忘れていないか確認してください。

Answer (score 1):

画像のオレンジ色の行の 1 行下の行では bcc32c が実行できているようですね。bcc32c は bcc32 の代替とのことです。

[BCC32C - RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/BCC32C)

> BCC32C は RAD Studio の 32 ビット Windows 向け C++ コンパイラです。RAD Studio では、BCC32（32 ビット Windows 向けの旧世代 C++ コンパイラ）の代わりに使用できるコンパイラとして BCC32C を提供しています。

ただ、bcc32c も「no such file or directory: 'hello.c'」と言ってるようですが、C:\study に hello.c は存在しますか？